# Kafka Connect instead of Flume Ingestion

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, real-time-data

I have been looking into the concepts and application of Kafka Connect, and I have even touched one project based on it in one of my intern. Now in my working scenario, now I am considering replacing the architecture of the our real time data ingestion platform which is currently based on flume -> Kafka with Kafka Connect and Kafka. 
The reason why I am considering the switch can be concluded mainly into:

1. But if we use flume we need to install the agent on each remote machine which generates tons of workload for further devops, especially at the place where I am working where the authority of machines is managed in a rigid way that maintaining utilities on machines belonging to other departments.
2. Another reason for the consideration is that the machines' os environment varies, if we install flumes on a variety of machines , some machine with different os and jdks(I have met some with IBM jdk) just cannot make flume work well which in worst case can result in zero data ingestion.

It looks with Kafka Connect we can deploy it in a centralized way with our Kafka cluster so that the develops cost can go down. Beside, we can avoid installing flumes on machines belonging to others and avoid the risk of incompatible environment to ensure the stable ingestion of data from every remote machine.

Besides, the most ingestion scenario is only to ingest real-time-written log text file on remote machines(on linux and unix file system)  into Kafka topics, that is it. So I won't need advanced connectors which is not supported in apache version of Kafka.

But I am not sure if I am understanding the usage or scenario of Kafka Connect the right way. Also I am wondering if Kafka Connect should be deployed on the same machine with the data source machines or if it is ok they resides on different machines. If they can be different then why flume requires the agent to be run on the same machine with the data source? So I wish someone more experienced can give me some lights on that.

Answer (score 2):

1. Is Kafka Connect appropriate for ingesting data to Kafka? yes
2. Does Kafka Connect run local to the data source? only if it has to (e.g. reading a local file with Kafka Connect spooldir plug, FilePulse plugin, etc ).
3. Should you rip out something that works and replace it with Kafka Connect? not unless it's fixing a problem that you have
4. If you're not using either yet, should you use Kafka Connect instead of Flume? Quite possibly.

Learn more about Kafka Connect here: https://dev.to/rmoff/crunchconf-2019-from-zero-to-hero-with-kafka-connect-81o

For file ingest alone there's other tools too like Filebeat too

Comment: Hi, could you please explain in a bit more detailed way that when Kafka Connect needs run local to the data source? Well, in my scenario we only need to track a few files in certain directory which can be captured by a simple regex matcher(now it is the built-in matched provided by flume)